# Auto increment by condition in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have 2 columns with ID1 AND ID2:

| ID1 | ID2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |

I want to get an auto-increment formula for ID2 - when ID1 changes, the ID2 should start from the beginning.

Comment: Do you mean, if ID1 changes, ID2 should be 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a solution using arrayformula, you could try in B2

```
=Arrayformula(if(A2:A="",,countifs(A2:A, A2:A, row(A2:A), "<="&row(A2:A))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below `COUNTIFS()` formula.

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A2,A2)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks. Anyway, is it a way to get the same result using ARRAYFORMULA?

Comment: @MaksymKatsovets If it works then please accept the answer (tick mark it as green).